# Create form not affected by ShowDialog()

Tags: c#

I'm currently doing a security assessment of an extremely large C# application.  I have wrote a tool to help me do the assessment that also runs in C#.  The entire application uses ShowDialog aka modal forms.  I'm trying to come up with a way where I can still use my tool (click on it for example) while modal dialog boxes are popped up.  I figure, this may require another thread or something else.  If anyone has any easy tips on a way to make it so that my form doesn't get blocked by ShowDialog, that would be great.

Comment: The work-around would be to use a mock dialog, but that means changing all of the code to get the dialog from a factory, using an interface. I don't think there's a work-around without altering source code.

Comment: I wish down-voters would at least have the decency to explain why. Down-voting and leaving helps no one. I think this is a decent question.

Answer (score 0):

The entire purpose in using a modal dialog is for it to block it's parent until it is dismissed.

Comment: Right, unfortunately this makes performing a security assessment with the toolchain we built more difficult since it's in the same project.  I understand this is the expected behavior but if anyone has a workaround that would be helpful.